# Openssl Identify (not verify) Root and Intermediate CA's of cert for automation

Tags: openssl

I have a scenario where I need to be able to script/automate adding the complete chain (root and intermediate) to existing ssl certs.

Our current process uses openssl to create a .p12 with the private key as well as a encrypted .pem from the .cer files that are generated both from our internal CA as well as ones from our 3rd party trusted root. This is to provide various possible format for the rather large variety of servers/devices that we provide these SSL certs for.

We have several instances though where the complete chain is needed in the .p12 or .pfx file. What complicates this is that we have multiple internal CA's as well as 3rd party.

What I need to be able to do is via openssl commands added to an existing script identify the exact Root/Intermediate CA's a .cer file was created/signed with, so I can pick the correct files to add to create the chain. The subject DN is not going to be unique enough in this instance, I was hoping to be able to retrieve and strip out the serial numbers of the root and intermediate CA's and use that as identifying filenames to insure uniqueness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the question stands, there's not much Stack Overflow can do to help you. You should probably decompose your job into tasks, and then ask a specific question about a problem you are encountering at each task. Or maybe, check [Rent-a-Coder](https://www.freelancer.com/campaign/0ABU1300014/) for someone who can develop your script for you.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. 

Is there a way to extract the Root and Intermediate CA's serial number using openssl?

Or, is there another method to match the Root and Intermediate CA listed in an individual cert against a set of files to be able to select the proper file for inclusion.

Comment: Yes. Try `openssl x509 -in <certificate> -text -noout | grep -i 'serial number'`. If the certificate is binary, then use `-inform DER`. If the certificate is PEM, use `-inform PEM`. Also see the [x509 man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509.html).